# Want to run a secondary node on a new machine and want to use the blockchain data of existing node

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network, core-lightning

I run a lightning node (umbrel, raspberry pi). I wanted to build a secondary node(c-lightning) on my laptop (ubuntu), from scratch. I followed some steps from [their github](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning) but I'm now confused the the step that says [`starting lightningd`](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning#starting-lightningd):

Once I install bitcoin - will it start downloading the blockchain data immediately? And how do I configure it such that it accesses the bitcoin chaindata from my existing umbrel node?

Thanks in advance, consider me a n00b who's willing to read up and learn.

Comment: Please ask questions separately - use the "Ask Question" button three times for three questions. You'll get better answers, this site will be a better organised set of questions+answers and therefore more people will benefit.